# Replicating filters from Instagram

Tags: iphone, ios, core-image, instagram, imagefilter

I am trying to replicate three filters from instagram within my iphone app, more specifically:

1. Sutro
2. X Pro 2
3. Toaster

I have been trying to combine different filters from CoreImages but can't seem to get what I want.

Has anyone already implemented these 3 filters and can help guide me to an answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you use any web based filters? php has some cool filters

Comment: I would like to do it on the device to limit network communication.

Comment: hrm. well github is a vast library of awesomem so check there. i found  this: https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

Comment: You can use kCGBlendMode for applying the inbuilt Core image filters to your images ..

Comment: paid library : http://www.binpress.com/app/photo-effects-sdk-for-ios/801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using the PhotoFX library found at [link](http://www.binpress.com/app/photo-effects-sdk-for-ios/801)

Answer (score 1):

I would give a try to GPUImage by Brad Larson that is even faster that CoreImage (GPU-accelerated filters) and has support for iOS 4:

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage